# ListView is not filled with data

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

In this application, the data is inserted in a edittext. Then, when you press enter, the application checks if the inserted data exists in a text file. If yes, the information in the text file is split and added to the listview.

The main operation works, but the listview is not populated with the data.

I try to change the `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` from the `onCreate` method to inside the `enterKey` listener. When I do this, the listview is filled, but always with the same data.

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final String TAG = "Main4Activity";

    ListView listView;

    Boolean scanOpenStatus;

    EditText editText4;

    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

        editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCodigo);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewXML);
        final List<HashMap<String, String>> listagem = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listagem, R.layout.layoutlist, new String[] {"Principal", "Sub"}, new int[] {R.id.textViewListViewMain, R.id.textViewListViewSub});
        final HashMap<String, String> dados = new HashMap<>();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setFocusable(false);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        editText4.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                boolean check = false;

                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) &&
                        (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {

                    String codigoLido = editText4.getText().toString().trim();
                    editText4.setText("");

                    if (!codigoLido.equals("")) {
                        try {

                            File caminhoTxt = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/lookupscangs1.txt");

                            if (caminhoTxt.exists()) {

                                try {

                                    String line;
                                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(caminhoTxt);
                                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                                    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                                        String[] codDesc = line.split(";");
                                        String codigo = codDesc[0];
                                        String descricao = codDesc[1];

                                        if (codigo.equals(codigoLido)) {

                                            dados.put("Principal", codigoLido);
                                            dados.put("Sub", descricao);
                                            listagem.add(dados);
                                            check = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    dados.put("Principal", codigoLido);
                                    dados.put("Sub", "Código Não Cadastrado!");
                                    listagem.add(dados);
                                    check = true;
                                }

                                catch (Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Catch 01: " + (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                            }

                        } catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Catch 02: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insira um Código!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
                editText4.requestFocus();
                return check;
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: First you always add an item that looks like "Credentials not found" while one would think you only want to add it if ctedentials are really not found. Second, you use same temporary variable dados to fill your list just hanging its data. As a result your list gets filled with references to dados. I don't think List.add() makes a copy of objects, it just stores reference. One way to fix it is to do dados=new Hashmap() before editing contents. That will alocate a new variable while old will still be accessible for your List. Third is do notify your ListView that data changed as others have said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried manually updating the display with

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yes, I did. No success.

Comment: Where did you add the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); line?

Comment: Hello Joey. I put notifyData in the onCreate block. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Vhox yes it is wrong. You need to notify adapter about changed data every time data changes after the change. Changes happen in your onKey event, not in your onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to solve this either add

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listagem, R.layout.layoutlist, new String[] {"Principal", "Sub"}, new int[] {R.id.textViewListViewMain, R.id.textViewListViewSub};listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in the try block at the bottom.

Comment: Hello Anand. Thanks for your answer. Actually, putting the adapter inside try block worked! But all items in the listview became the same. For example. If I insert "Hello" in the list, so "Hello" appears in the list. Next, if I insert "Hi", instead of appear "Hello" and "Hi" in the list, it is showed "Hi" and "Hi". Just o continue the example, next if I insert "Bye", it will show "Bye", "Bye", "Bye". I am not getting why...